# Hosted window in WPF doesn't get mouse messages

Tags: wpf, events, windows-messages, hwndhost, wpf-interop

Taking it a bit further than hosting WinForms user controls in my WPF application, I am actually hosting Delphi forms, i.e. top level windows. I am doing so through the voodoo in blog post [How To Host Top-Level HWNDs In WPF](http://marcozhou.wordpress.com/2007/02/24/).

Nearly everything works perfectly. I send a COM server, built in Delphi, a menu path string, and it sends back a window handle, which I pass to the host control described in the blog. The Delphi window receives nearly all events (rather, Windows Messages) correctly, without any intervention on my part.

The only problem is the buttons. They receive a click event/message fine, and work, but now the Delphi guys have added new icons to the buttons, and each button has an active icon, a hover icon, and a click icon. They receive none of the messages they should to change these icons. Why do nearly all messages work except these? What can I read and or do to try and correct this?

Comment: How do you know they don't receive the message? Have you checked that with a tool like Spy++ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460756.aspx

Comment: @SimonMourier I assume they don't get the message because there, whatever it is in Delphi, "mouseover" events don't fire and change the colour. In the pure Delphi app this works.

Comment: So you should check this with Spy++ or alternative tools, otherwise you may be chasing the wrong mouse

Comment: is it possible for you to post a working sample? may we have a look.

Comment: Did u capture the mouse?

Answer (score 0):

In MouseOver event, send some user message and catch it.

[WPF and Win32 Interoperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms742522.aspx)
HWNDs inside WPF > Notable Differences in Input behavior

> While the mouse is over the HwndHost, your application does not receive WPF mouse events, and the value of the WPF property IsMouseOver will be false.

Comment: The events are Delphi events, handled in Delphi code. This works fine until that window is 'hosted' by my window. Then it becomes a lower down matter than WPF or Delphi code.